# how do you test an expression without it running?

Tags: python, user-interface, typeconverter

Is there a way to test if an expression leads to an error
without running it normally (which would lead to a program crash)?
In particular, the chunk `int(temp[1])` without knowing whether or not `temp[1]` is a number (as in a string number such as "10" or "142")? The reason I'm trying to do this is to implement error handling involving in regards to user input.

Comment: The concept of expections is to handle them when they happen. Trying to prevent them in advance can lead to race conditions and other problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`type(temp[1])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) or [`isinstance(temp[1], int)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to check types. To specifically check if strings are numbers, use [`temp[1].isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit).

Answer (score 0):

You could try `if isinstance(temp[1], int)`. This checks if `temp[1]` is an instance of the `int` class.

Another way to do this is to catch the error itself. That way you know for a fact that it causes the error. For example:

```py
try:
    int(temp[1])
except ValueError:
    print("The variable temp[1] can't be changed to an int.")
```

Comment: Why not write `if type(temp[1]) is int`, or even better `if isinstance(temp[1], int)`? Using `type(0)` seems a bit cryptic to me. NB: Comparing types is not really recommended in Python. Your "try-except" solution is much better, IMHO. Although there could be reasons to specifically check for a certain type, but that's not really clear from the question.

Comment: @wovano Good point. You're right: `if type(temp[1]) == type(int)` *is* a overkilling it a little. Will remember this in the future!